# Retrieving content of a document using firestore in React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I'm new to React Native.

I'm building a mobile application and I would ultimately like to display a user's information that was retrieved from a Firestore database on the screen.

My current issue is that I'm unable to run this code that I received from the firestore documentation. I believe that you need to add the keyword async before you can use the keyword await, but where do I add the keyword async here? If I add it to the UserHome function I get the error "Objects are not valid as a react child". Please let me know how I can get this function running. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
export function UserHome({ navigation }) {
  const route = useRoute();
  const userID = route.params?.userID;

  const docRef = doc(db, "userInfo", userID);
  const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
  if (docSnap.exists()) {
    console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
  } else {
    // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
    console.log("No such document!");
  } 

  const handleSignOut = () => {
    signOut(auth)
      .then(() => {
        navigation.replace("Home");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // An error happened.
      });
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>You're officially in!!</Text>
      <Button
        containerStyle={{
          padding: 10,
          height: 45,
          overflow: "hidden",
          borderRadius: 20,
          backgroundColor: "#8252ff",
        }}
        disabledContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: "grey" }}
        style={{
          fontSize: 18,
          color: "white",
          textAlign: "center",
        }}
        onPress={handleSignOut}
      >
        Sign Out
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: The error message means that your UserHome function is returning an object instead of JSX/HTML, for example 

return <p>UserHome</p>;

Comment: Likely an issue in your markup/JSX. Would need to see what you are returning to understand better.  Like @ArnoTeigseth is saying, UserHome is an object which is invalid.

Comment: But this error only happens when I use the keyword "async". Why is that happening?

Comment: You have a bigger problem if UserHome is a react component: You're running code with side effects (and/or async code) in its render function.

The solution is to fetch data outside this component, or in something like useEffect({ … },[]) to then update the component with the newly fetched data.

Comment: Just updated my questions so you can all see the full code. @ArnoTeigseth Does your answer still apply?

Comment: @davidocodes you can do something like this ```  useEffect(() => {
      getDoc(doc(db, "userInfo", userID))
      .then(docSnap => {
          if (docSnap.exists()) {
            console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
          } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
          } 
      });
  }, []); // empty [] = run once after the page has rendered```
(useEffect doesn't allow async in its own body, but you can export it into another function and make that one async)